# Cannot find a button inside the shadow DOM using Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I'm trying to find and click on a button inside the shadow DOM using Cypress.io.

I've tried various class names, with combinations of get/find and the .shadow() command.

I'm getting this error in Cypress:

> "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected the subject to host a
> shadow root, but never found it."

Here is some code of the react app I'm testing (with the button id highlighted)

[app code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enoxg.png)

Below is the latest Cy code I've tried.

```
    cy.get('*[class^="MuiInputBase-input"]').shadow()
    cy.find('div[id="search-clear"]')
      .invoke('show')
      .click()
```

The button I'm trying to find and click on (it becomes visible upon mouse-over).

[button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wva6U.png)

Any ideas on how to target this element?

Answer (score 2):

You have to chain `.find(selector)` after `.shadow()`

like:

```js
cy.get('.MuiInputBase-input').shadow()
    .find('#search-clear')
    .invoke('show')
    .click()
```

[example in documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow#Examples)

side note:
Why are you using `*[class^="MuiInputBase-input"]` and `div[id="search-clear"]`
instead of `.MuiInputBase-input` and `#search-clear`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, I edited it to 'find' as you were answering XD.
I still get the same error using .find()

Comment: But have you chained it after shadow?

Comment: Notice that I'm not using another `cy.find('#search-clear')` but i'm using something that will in one line look like this `cy.get('.MuiInputBase-input').shadow().find('#search-clear')`

Comment: @chad_jw When you use `cy.find('#search-clear')` you are not searching shadow DOM

Comment: I have chained .shadow() AFTER .find() and BEFORE .find() - either combo cannot find the shadow.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. cy.get('input[placeholder="Enter title of project here"]').shadow().find('div').type('Test') is not finding the shadow root

Answer (score 0):

For me, my components were a couple layers deep. You have to inspect the CSS to see it.

```
    cy.get("app-root")
      .shadow()
      .find("page-login")
      .shadow()  // <-- Note: another shadow
      .find("[data-cy='input-text-email']") // using custom data attr for stability
      .type('email@ymail.com');
```